# restricting WMS tile extents

Tags: openlayers-3, wms

I'm brand new to openlayers, I've just been reading the docs today since I have a need to do some testing with it. I'd like to know if there's a way in openlayers to restrict the maximum geographic extent in a WMS tile request.

I've read that WMS bounding boxes are generated automagically, which is neat - but I have some issues with WMS requests on very large datasets which tend to make the underlying WMS server struggle. That's not really change-able, so we need to work around it, and one strategy is to request only small subsets at a time (~5 or 10 degree squares at most).

So - is there a way in openlayers to say 'get me at most 5 degrees by 5 degrees in a single WMS request, and build my map layer from those'?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can set extent for your layer in such way:

```
new ol.layer.Tile( {
    extent: ol.proj.transformExtent([30, 30, 50, 50], "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857"),
    // your WMS source and other code
```

Please, make sure to use right projection. Example was given in case your map is in web mercator.